# Android Callback Method

Tags: android, android-activity

When I read Android Training , I saw a description for the activity-lifecycle:

> When your activity is stopped, the Activity object is kept resident in
>   memory and is recalled when the activity resumes. You don’t need to
>   re-initialize components that were created during any of the callback
>   methods leading up to the Resumed state. The system also keeps track
>   of the current state for each View in the layout, so if the user
>   entered text into an EditText widget, that content is retained so you
>   don't need to save and restore it.

I'm confused, if I don't need to re-initialize any components, why do I have to handle data or any something on callback method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take Camera as an example.

You don't need to reinitialize any component, but you need to reinitialize the camera when the activity resumed. Component arne't the only part of an activity. Most applications also need to access system resources. You release these resources when your application gets paused or stopped, so you must reinitialize them again when your application is resumed. And Android may destroy your application in some circumstances (memory not enough, etc.) So you have to release and reinitialize resources again.

Moreover, there might be some internal state of your application. For example a book reader. You need to record the progress. This internal state are not components but you have to save them when your activity get paused.

The following code is sourced from Android documentation. Old mirror available [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html):

> ```
> @Override
> public void onPause() {
>     super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
>
>     // Release the Camera because we don't need it when paused
>     // and other activities might need to use it.
>     if (mCamera != null) {
>         mCamera.release()
>         mCamera = null;
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
>
>     // Get the Camera instance as the activity achieves full user focus
>     if (mCamera == null) {
>         initializeCamera(); // Local method to handle camera init
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That description applies only to the stopped state. A stopped activity can also be destroyed, so the idea is that you save your data in onStop() in case the activity is subsequently destroyed. While there is an onDestroy() callback, it is not guaranteed to be called. onStop() can be relied upon to be called when your activity transitions from paused to stopped.
Note that in pre-Honeycomb versions of Android even onStop() can't necessarily be relied on, and onPause() should be used to save state. Honeycomb and subsequent versions will not kill an activity until the onStop() method has returned.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is stopped (ie the user presses home OR he handles an incoming call), the process (and the contained activity) of your application is not destroyed.

In this scenario, your components are already initialized (that means, they are showing what they were showing before your activity was stopped) and when the activity is brought to front again (the user reopens your app), you don't have to restore any sort of data.

However, after a while, the os may decide to reclame your app's resources and decide to kill the process (or the user may press back button from your home activity). In this other scenario, you are supposed to save the state of your activity in order to restore it whenever the user gets back to your app.

You can use [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

or just store to preferences on onStop()